# Windows Server 2012 Remote Desktop Server slow GPO applied

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, terminal-services, group-policy

I have a Remote Desktop Server 2012 R2. I have a loopback enabled GPO with a few settings. Then I've got a few user-configurated GPO's which are applied. They are working just fine. However, I'm having issues with one specific GPO that runs a .vbs script applying a shortcut on the desktop. I've got to wait around 5-10 minutes before the shortcut appears on the desktop. I a bit blaffeled by it, because all the other GPO's are working just fine.

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this.  a new "FEATURE" in Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1 is to delay login scripts 5 minutes.  That's helpful.  You have to disable this via GPO here:

Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy\Configure Logon Script Delay

set the value to 0